# Singleton behaviour of javascript object

Tags: javascript, singleton

I want to have singleton kind of object whose value gets changed during multiple events across multiple pages. This object is used to bind the ui in various pages.

I have a 'main.js' file :

```
var obj = { flag : false } ;

 // call back method
 function click() { 
  obj.flag = true;
  }
```

and  in my next.js file

```
 // call back method
  function click() { 
  alert(obj.flag); // **alerts false** . It should alert **true** instead.
  }
```

Is there a way to persist the value other than using the window.name property ? or am I following the wrong approach

Comment: Cookies or local storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML5 localStorage**.
As described in the documentations ([Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) etc.), localStorage supports string key/value pairs.

Therefore you need to use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) to save your object in the storage.

```
var obj = { flag : false };

// Save the object in the storage
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));

// Get the object from storage
var objectData = localStorage.getItem('obj');
var originalObject = JSON.parse(objectData );

alert(originalObject.flag);
```

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FdhzU/